# Firestore whereArrayContains doesn't work when more than 1 value in array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document "users" that has an array field of "languages" and "country". Every user spreaks several languages so for one user it is

```
user1,

   languages: english, spanish, italian
   country: "UK"
user2,
   languages: english
   country: "UK"
```

[image]
[image]

My query is as follows:

```
   query = db.collection("users");
   query = query.whereEqualTo("country", "UK");
   query = query.whereArrayContains("languages", "English");
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@NonNull QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                return;
            }
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                for (DocumentSnapshot document : snapshotList) {
 String country= document.getString("country");
     Log.wtf(TAG, country);
    }
 } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ");
            }
        }
    });
```

Result is only data for "user2"  is returned, because it has only one field in the array languages. Althoug "user1" also has English as a language value, it this user's data isn't returned.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact documents you're hoping to match with this query.

Comment: Updated CodeText, inserted Screenshots,

Comment: So you say that in your logcat only one result is printed, "UK", right?

Comment: yes it should be two. When I leave both users with only English i get two and if I add more languages to user 2 I get no result back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an index like this:

- country     -   Ascending
- languages   -   Arrays

---

1. Go to indexes

[image]

2. Add a new index exactly like this:

[image]